# ¿Como calcular entre dos fechas?

Tags: php, formularios, date, depuración

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio para calcular cuánto ha pasado desde el 1 de enero a la fecha introducida. Me obligan a utilizar switch case y no puedo usar la función `mktime()`, y no termino de hacer funcionar el código que resta las fechas. El error que me da es el siguiente: **Edito**, el profesor me ha indicado que lo haga extrayendo el mes y sumando la cantidad de días, pero no me funciona:

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
        <title> Calendario</title>
        <body>
            <center><h3>Introduce una fecha en formato dd/mm/aa para saber cuánto ha transcurrido desde el 1 de enero de 2016:</h3></center>
            <date-util format="dd/MM/yy"></date-util>
            <form name="Formulario" method="post" action="ejercicio5.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Fecha inicial:
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="date" name="fecha1" value="dd/MM/yy" required>
                        <input type="dare" name="fecha16" value="01/01/16">
                    </td>

                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="Enviar">
                        <input type="reset" name="Reestablecer">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**:

```
    <?php
//Definición de variables
$entrada = (string) $_POST['fecha1'];
$fechafija = (string) "2016-01-01";
echo "$entrada <br/>";
echo "$fechafija <br/>";
$diaentrada =  substr($entrada, 8, 9);
$diafijo =  substr($fechafija, 8, 9);
$mes = substr($entrada, 5, 6);
$numentrada = (int) $diaentrada;
$numfijo = (int) $diafijo;
//Ejercicio
echo "$numentrada y $numfijo el número de mes es $mes <br/>";
switch ($mes) {
    case '1':
            $dif = $diaentrada - $diafijo;
            echo "Han pasado $dif días";
        break;
        case '2':
            $dif2 = $diaentrada - $diafijo +28;
            echo "han pasado $dif2 días";
            break;
        case '3':
            $dif3 = $diaentrada - $diafijo +28+31;
            echo "Han pasado $dif3 días";
            break;
        case '4':
            $dif4 = $diaentrada - $diafijo +30+31+28;
            echo "Han pasado $dif4 días";
            break;
        case '5':
            $dif5 = $diaentrada - $diafijo +30+31+28+30;
            echo "Han pasado $dif5 días";
            break;
        case '6':
            $dif6 = $diaentrada - $diafijo +30+31+28+30+30;
            echo "Han pasado $dif6 días";
            break;
        case '7':
            $dif7 = $diaentrada - $diafijo +30+31+28+30+30+31;
            echo "Han pasado $dif7 días";
            break;
        case '8':
            $dif6 = $diaentrada - $diafijo +30+31+28+30+30+31+30;
            echo "Han pasado $dif8 días";
            break;
        case '9':
            $dif9 = $diaentrada - $diafijo +30+31+28+30+30+31+30+31;
            echo "Han pasado $dif9 días";
            break;
        case '10':
            $dif10 = $diaentrada - $diafijo +30+31+28+30+30+31+30+31+31;
            echo "Han pasado $dif10 días";
            break;
        case '11':
            $dif11 = $diaentrada - $diafijo +30+31+28+30+30+31+30+31+31+30;
            echo "Han pasado $dif11 días";
            break;
        case '12':
            $dif12 = $diaentrada - $diafijo +30+31+28+30+30+31+30+31+31+30+31;
            echo "Han pasado $dif12 días";
            break;
    default:
        echo "No funciono :D";
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) para devolver la diferencia entre dos objetos DateTime:

```
<?php
$fecha1 = new DateTime($_POST["fecha1"]);
$fecha2 = new DateTime($_POST["fecha2"]);

$diffDias = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);

// solo >= PHP 7 
$fechas = $fecha1 <=> $fecha2;

switch ($fechas) {
    case 0:
        echo "Es la misma fecha";
        break;
    case -1:
        echo "En $diffDias->d dias";
        break;
     case 1:
        echo "Hace $diffDias->d dias";
        break;
}
```

**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/48b8a9666412cbe0f2349804aa99f9154eb22d73)**

Comment: Ésta debe ser la forma más rara de usar un `switch` que he visto en mi vida.

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo

Comment: Para que me coja los valores del formulario cómo lo hago? o sea utilizar $_POST con esas funciones

Comment: @ras212 - he actualizado la respuesta... por favor no cambies la pregunta original ya que en realidad ya mi respuesta no es *válida*...en vez haz un nuevo post con las nuevas dudas

Comment: Los valores que me dan entre fechas no son coherentes

Comment: Puedes explicarte mejor? Que es lo que no te cuadra?